# script chamado uma vez, mas vira dois processos

Tags: bash, shell, background, processo

Tenho aqui um script para testar uma função em segundo plano.

Quando rodo é lançado dois processos e eu não entendi o porque.

Um para no "sleep 20", e o outro roda eternamente.

```
#!/bin/bash

back(){
    n=0
    while [ 1 ]
    do      
        echo $n
        n=$(($n+1))
        sleep 5
    done
}

back &
sleep 20
exit
```

comando "ps -a" na chamada:

```
 PID    TTY      TIME      CMD
 8964   pts/2    00:00:00  backgroundteste
 8965   pts/2    00:00:00  backgroundteste
 8966   pts/2    00:00:00  sleep
 8982   pts/2    00:00:00  sleep
```

depois do "sleep 20":

```
PID    TTY      TIME      CMD
8965   pts/2    00:00:00  backgroundteste
9268   pts/2    00:00:00  sleep
```

depois esquece...

Porque?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este comando

```
back &
```

cria um processo em background.

Mesmo depois que o script original terminou uma cópia dele fica rodando em background, por causa do "&" acima.

Comment: Mas uma chamada a "backgroudteste" criou dois processos "backgroundteste". O script "backgroundteste" não chama a si mesmo para isso acontecer.

Comment: O script origina fica no ar por 20 segundos após chamar a função "back" em background. Nesses 20 segundos vão existir os dois processos "backgroundteste". Passados os 20 segundos o script inicial termina, mas o processo em background continua pra sempre por causa do loop infinito "while [ 1 ]". A função "back" está "amarrada" no script, porque é uma função criada dentro do script, então no ps o que aparece é o "backgroundteste". (Na verdade cada processo "backgroundteste" é uma instância do bash interpretando o script.)

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado.